# Windzone unable to bend trees

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on unity 5.5.2, using terrain tree creator i created trees over the terrain but facing an issue the trees created do not bend while using windzone. Tried changing setting of windzone did not help.

**Tree setting**

[image]

**Windzone setting**

[image]

Comment: Can you show your windzone settings?

Comment: Do the branches and leaves move at all?

Comment: nothing moves ,it is a low poly tree !

Answer (score 2):

Select the tree type in the inspector, select "Edit Trees" and set the **bend value** to a value between 0 and 1.

If you set it to 1 they will move quite a bit in the wind; the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-Trees.html) recommend a value of 0.1 to 0.3.

**EDIT**

Looking at your Object name it appears that you got your tree from [this asset package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/76796). Those trees have simple low-poly meshes and act as a simple shape - ergo will not react to windzones like trees created using the [Unity Tree Creator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/tree-FirstTree.html).

The easiest way to get a tree to react to the windzone is to create it through Unity's own tree creator.

Alternatively you will need to code the movement yourself.

Comment: Tried doing it, had no effect

Comment: Is their any way of bending a low poly tree ?

Comment: You can make them lean over easily enough but bending them would require deforming the mesh somehow or splitting them into separate objects

Comment: How do I make them lean over a direction

Comment: You could rotate them using code or in the editor. If you want to do this over time you would need to use code.